# Can we regard field operator $\Psi (x)$ as $a_{x}^{\dagger }$ ,$a_{x}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In real scalar CG-field, do we have $a_{x}^{\dagger }$ and $a_{x}$ operators?

Because we have $a_{p}^{\dagger }$ and $a_{p}$ ,
also the relation
$\Psi (x)=\int dp\, \,    a^{\dagger }e^{-ipx-i\omega t}+ae^{ipx+i\omega t}$

Since
$a_{p}^{\dagger }|0 \rangle=|p\rangle$  meaning a state with one particle of momentum p

Then I wish to have something similar,

$a_{x}^{\dagger }|0\rangle=|x\rangle$ meaning a state with one particle of location x

$\Psi (x) |0 \rangle=\int dp\, \,    e^{-ipx}|p\rangle=|x\rangle$  meaning a state with one particle localized in x

$|x,x',x''\rangle$ meaning a state with three particles localized in x x' x''

So I think $\Psi (x)$ is $a_{x}^{\dagger }$, because $a_{x}^{\dagger }|0\rangle=|x\rangle$,

or I am wrong $\Psi (x) |0 \rangle=\int dp\, \,    e^{-ipx}|p\rangle=|\Psi (x)\rangle$  which is different from $|x\rangle$

$\Psi (x) =\Psi^{\dagger } (x)$ implies $a_{x}^{\dagger }=a_{x}$ , then $a_{x}^{\dagger }|0\rangle=|x\rangle=a_{x}|0\rangle=0$ wrong!

Are there well defined $a_{x}^{\dagger }$ and $a_{x}$?

Comment: In solid state tight binding model, we often write Hamiltonian as sum of $b_{i}^{\dagger }a_{j}+a_{j}^{\dagger }b_{i}$, these are the creation operators of real space. Well in QFT, it is integration over $\Psi (x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have *free field* operators $a_x$ and $a^\dagger_x$ because the excitations at nearby locations are *coupled* because of the derivative in the lagrangian density.

When you exploit translational symmetry in the theory and fourier transform, you go to a basis where modes with momentum $k$ do not couple to modes with momentum $k^\prime$. So you can write free-field operators as above.

If you insisted on constructing creation/annihilation operators at each point, they would couple nearby points and the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian would look like something in your comment.

If you're okay with that, then you're right in identifying $a_x \equiv \Psi(x)$

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. The issue is that in QFT we reduce spacetime coordinates from observables to mere parameters of our fields.

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, you have time $t$ as a parameter governing the evolution of your states. Note that there is *no* operator that corresponds to time!

To implement relativity, we need to deal with space and time at the same level. This means to degrade space to a mere parameter in our theory. Our operators (like your $\Psi(x)$) now not only depend on time (which the operators in non-relativistic QM do in the Heisenberg picture), but they also depend on space. A quantization procedure like in regular QM is no longer available.

Note that the quantities that appear in the commutators that you impose in the quatization procedure are *not* $\vec x, \vec p$, but $\Psi, \Pi$, where $\Pi$ is the conjugate momentum to the field $\Psi$ and not the momentum operator that appears e.g. in the Poincare algebra.